# How do I enable the typescript compilation task to use the "--incremental" flag?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, task

I cannot find a explanation of how to enable the "incremental" flag (alongside "watch") in the `tasks.json` file.

Here is my `tasks.json`:

```json
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "build",
            "type": "typescript",
            "tsconfig": "tsconfig.json",
            "option": "watch",
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

This is the equivalent of running `tsc --watch`. But how can I make it the equivalent of `tsc --watch --incremental`?